# How to fix Resharper object initializer indentation as method argument

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, code-formatting

**Resharper 2016.2**

Current formatting

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = dbCustomers.Select(customer => new Customer
                                                     {
                                                         Name = customer.Name,
                                                         Address = customer.Address,
                                                         Number = customer.Number
                                                     });
```

Expected formatting

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = dbCustomers.Select(customer => new Customer
{
    Name = customer.Name,
    Address = customer.Address,
    Number = customer.Number
});
```

Which Resharper 2016.2 configuration can fix that?

**Please note, initializer is inside argument brackets, not in variable.**

Comment: Have you tried this: Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Other -> Align Multiline Constructs -> Array, object and collection initializer

Comment: @OscarSiauw: Yes, this option is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has just started to work without any changes in R# settings after **update to 2016.3 version**.

Answer (score 1):

If still someone needs help with this try this:
Resharper Options --> Code Editing --> C# --> Formatting Style --> Other --> Uncheck "Array, object and collection initializer".

Then in: Resharper Options --> Code Editing --> C# --> Formatting Style --> Braces Layout --> "Array and object initializer" = "At next line (BSD Style)".

You could also do this, which makes it a little bit nicer:
Resharper Options --> Code Editing --> C# --> Formatting Style --> Line Breaks and Wrappings --> "Wrap object and collection initializer" = "Chop if long or multiline".

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Hope it helps!

**Go to Resharper -> Options from Visual Studio menu bar.**

> On the tree view:

**Code Editing** -> **C#** -> **Formatting Style** -> **Braces Layout**

> On the right panel:

**Array and object initializer**

- Expand the options combo box.
- Pick `At the next Line (BSD style)` (3rd option).

[image: Formatting style]

Comment: This option is enabled. It does not change the formatting as expected. The problem is, that initializer is inside method arguments list.